# what is a login server?

Tags: login

Can anybody tell me what a login server is ? From what i know - it is used to login to a private network from outside the network. Is that the only functionality of a login server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where I work, "login server" simply means a system whose primary purpose is to provide interactive (i.e., shell via ssh) access to our user community.  It can also act as a gateway into our network environment.

In other environments, "login server" may refer to something completely different -- for example, some web authentication products refer to the authentication server as the "login server" (http://www.pubcookie.org/docs/install-login.html).  This may actually be the more common use; a search on Google for "login server" leads to lots of web-centric information.